# 401 error when trying GET request to Hawkbit Server with Gateway Security Token

Tags: docker, http, authentication, postman, eclipse-hawkbit

**Q1:**

I'm running a Hawkbit server on localhost in a docker container and activated the option "Allow a gateway to authenticate and manage multiple targets through a gateway security token" in the settings of the web UI that I access via http://localhost:8080/.

Now I'm using Postman to send a GET request to http://localhost:8080/default/controller/v1/25 with the header

```
key: GatewayToken, value: <The gateway token shown in the Hawkbit web UI>
```

Using this header, I'm supposed to be able to authenticate my Postman client against the Hawkbit server (compare e.g. https://www.eclipse.org/hawkbit/concepts/authentication/), however I'm always getting a "401 Unauthorized" response.

Even if I enable "Allow targets to download artifacts without security credentials" which should enable any client to get a ressource even without authentification, I get a 401.

What am I doing wrong?

**Q2:**

The Hawkbit server is running in Docker started via "docker-compse up -d" as described here: https://www.eclipse.org/hawkbit/gettingstarted/

In order to solve the problem of *Q1*, I wanted to check the output of Hawkbit inside the container, but I'm not too familiar with docker and couldn't find out how. I was able to get inside the conainer using

```
docker exec -it docker_hawkbit_1 /bin/sh
```

which bring me into the container's file system at /opt/hawkbit. But that's not what I was looking for. How can I see the log/output of the Hawkbit/Spring Boot application running inside the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1:** 
The key of the request should not be GatewayToken, but Authorization. The header of the request will then look as follows:

```
key: Authorization, value: GatewayToken <token>
```

**Q2:**
Try the following command to see the logs:

```
docker logs -f docker_hawkbit_1
```